# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.Document org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AfterLoadEvent.getDocument

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, bson

In my springboot application, I am upgrading spring-data-mongodb-encrypt dependency from version 1.3.0 to 2.3.1 and I am getting this exception

The current springboot version in my application is 1.4.2, and I am using open JDK 15. As updating the springboot version may require lots of other dependency updates, is there any other way to resolve the issue

The full stack trace is

```
2021-08-19 13:10:21.736 SpringApplication:839 - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheContainer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.bson.Document org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AfterLoadEvent.getDocument()'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at com.cat.MSiteApplication.main(MSiteApplication.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.bson.Document org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AfterLoadEvent.getDocument()'
    at com.bol.secure.CachedEncryptionEventListener.onAfterLoad(CachedEncryptionEventListener.java:35)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AbstractMongoEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractMongoEventListener.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AbstractMongoEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractMongoEventListener.java:33)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.maybeEmitEvent(MongoTemplate.java:1671)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2293)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1949)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1767)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1750)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:624)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:357)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.cat.CacheContainer.getCacheData(CacheContainer.java:31)
    at com.cat.CacheContainer.init(CacheContainer.java:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 1):

NoSuchMethodError is typically a dependency version problem.  You may have introduced one or more duplicate jars by upgrading only the spring-data-mongodb-encrypt version.  It's also possible that due to the coordination between 2 jars, a method that was expected to exist in the newer mongo dependency just does not exist in the jar that its calling because its on an older version.

For spring-boot, you typically want to use their spring-boot-dependencies as a parent pom or as an imported pom to your dependency management section of your pom. Additionally, use the starter jars as these contain versions of spring dependencies that behave nicely with each other. This will allow Spring to manage the version of your jars so you won't have to figure out which version of each jar works well with every other jar.

Example pom.xml with dependency management and Mongo Data Starter:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <!-- Notice the lack of version specified here.  The above spring-boot-dependencies will set this appropriately -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To resolve your issue, you have a few options:

1. Revert to the previous version of spring-data-mongodb-encrypt if you don't have a specific need for the newer version
2. Coordinate and update all spring libraries in your project using the method described above